# InfoPath 2010 changing Date/Time/second Formula

Tags: infopath2010

I have this formula in a textbox to generate the date, time, and seconds. I want to format the date to mm/dd/yyyy instead of yyyy/mm/dd

```
translate(now(), "_-:T", "")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use functions concat, substring, translate

```
concat(substring(translate(now(), "_-:T", ""), 5, 2), "/", substring(translate(now(), "_-:T", ""), 7, 2), "/", substring(translate(now(), "_-:T", ""), 1, 4))
```

**OUTPUT:
09/12/2014**